# Django REST Framework: enforce content type

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, content-type

I have an API endpoint for an IoT device and I am trying to minimize the size of the HTTP request. I would like to not specify the content type in the request header and ask DRF to always use `application/json`.
How to do that?

Comment: Can you given an example on how you do this right now?

Comment: I have an IOT device making calls to my jango API service and I don't specify the content type. It works fine. What platform are you using?